# NSFW story about a stowaway girl on an alien's ship

Tags: story-identification

I remember not a ton, but for sure he had four balls and called it his "quad." I also vaguely remember some implied hypno-pheromone stuff going on and rhythms being relevant somehow.

It may have been a DeviantArt thing, so who knows, but it would be funny/neat to find again to see how my memory compares.

Comment: Was this a _short_ story? And in roughly which year did you read it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is the online story [Three Square Meals](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/13412677/1/Three-Square-Meals).

The spaceship owner is *John* and the stowaway is *Alyssa*:

> Careful not to look up at the blinding overhead lights, John searched the room thoroughly. It was not until he returned to the doorway panel that he noticed a faint dusty scuffmark on the other side of the door. Having meticulously scrubbed that section of floor in an OCD fury before landing, he knew that someone or something had come aboard with the cargo at Karron.
> John resealed the cargo bay and began to sweep the ship. The Fool's Gold was not huge, having only the cockpit, his cabin, the hold, a secondary cabin, his recreation room and the ship's storage. He found no signs of life in the cabins or cockpit and there wasn't anywhere to hide in the recreation room, consisting as it did of a dining table, a comfy sofa and a small but functional kitchen. That meant his interloper was in the storage room. John took a deep breath and readied himself for action before stepping into the doorway of the final room. Raising his auto shotgun, he looked through the scope and the targeting grid depicted the room in expected blues, with the occasional red glow from the overhead lights. He turned slowly, carefully checking any potential hiding places through the scope, until he finally faced a storage compartment near the back of the room. A telltale red glow was edging the door to this particular compartment, signifying a warm presence inside.
> "I know you're in there, come on out!" John barked at the storage compartment, keeping a wary distance. He waited pensively to the count of ten, but there was no movement from the compartment.
> "Either you come out in 5 seconds, or I unload this shotgun and space your corpse!" John shouted at the compartment door.
> He heard some kind of squeak from the compartment and the storage door swung open slowly. A dirty, unkempt figure stepped timidly out of the compartment and into the bright lights of the storage room.

The scene where Alyssa discovers that John has four testicles is (this is NSFW):

> Alyssa took a nervous couple of steps and then sank to her knees. Face to face with his enormous cock, she licked her lips nervously. She looked at his swollen dick, standing tall above his 4 balls.
> "Holy fuck!!! You've got four balls!" she gasped, gawping at the cluster of orbs.
> "I did say I'm slightly different. I call them my quad," John explained helpfully.

I found this on the [FanFiction](https://www.fanfiction.net/) web site using [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=stowaway%20four%20testicles%20%22quad%22%20science%20fiction%20novel). It was about ten hits down the list of results. Googling this was an ... erm ... *interesting* experience but I am reasonable sure the trauma will ease eventually.

Comment: Wow, that's dedication.  Way to take one for the team! ;)